Facebook Sharing Debugger is returning a 403 error when testing my website's links
For a while now, I've had a problem with Facebook's Sharing Debugger. When I try posting the links to my Wordpress site to test/precache them for sharing, they return code 403. It mentions that I must allow "facebookexternalhit" on my robots.txt file, which is already allowed.
Whenever I scrape a page of my site with Facebook's sharing debugger, my server replies with code 200, verified on the server logs, but Facebook reports 403. I tried Iframely's debugger, and it works like a charm.
Whenever I scrape the robots.txt file, I get code 206.
My website is https://www.pokecenterblog.pt.
I did the following:

disabled all Wordpress plugins.

cleared the Wordpress cache.

specifically allowed facebookexternalhit on robots.txt.

tried disabling the firewall.

tried disabling bot protection.

asked the host for help.

asked Facebook for help, both on their Dev forum as well as their Facebook group, with little to no help.

used Facebook's Troubleshooter (cUrl command), which returns code 200.


What do I need to do to get that sweet code 200? I'm honestly at a loss. Please help. Thank you.

Can you check your server logs to see how it treats a request from Facebook? Looking at the log file for one of my sites, Facebook first requests the robots.txt file, followed by a request for the page and a request for the og image. Your host could be blocking Facebook’s bot before it ever gets to your robots.txt file.

Hi, thanks for answering.
Both Wordfence's traffic analyzer and the host's logs return code 200 toFacebook's crawler hits.

It’s strange that your server is reporting 200 but Facebook is saying 403. It’s even stranger that Facebook’s Sharing Debugger lists all of the og fields as complete. I’m just guessing, but maybe rework your site so it validates on the W3 HTML Validator.

The thing is, it's not just me this is happening to. I've noted that the same thing has been happening to at least 2 other people, and Facebook is silent.

I am having this same issue right now. Facebook never seems to even try to send an actual request to my website, and I've even validated the domain (using a TXT record) on Facebook.
In the past, I seldom had issues with this, but only began trying to post on Facebook again recently.
I also had this problem on LinkedIn, but when I used their link previewer, the link previews worked again.

Sorry to hear that, @MaxCandocia. A few days ago, the Sharing Debugger started working better (occasionally returning the desired code 200), and now it seems to be working fine. At least fine, per Facebook standards.
